# How does Structured Streaming plan logical plan of streaming query for every micro-batch?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I set up a small test on my laptop that does the following:

I created a Kafka topic with a few 1000 messages where each message contains a few rows with each row having about 100 columns.

Create 300 quite complex Spark columns in a List[Column]. No aggregations.

On setting up the stream from Kafka I set .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 1) so only one message is processed in each mini-batch.

I then apply the columns to the mini-batches consisting of just one message.

```
val testStream = myStream
  .select(manyTestCols :_*)
  .writeStream
  .format("console")
  .outputMode("append")
  .start()
  .awaitTermination()
```

Spark takes about 10 seconds to process each message.

I then change maxOffsetsPerTrigger to .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 1000) so 1000 messages are processed in each mini-batch.

Spark takes about 11 seconds to process all 1000 messages in each mini-batch.

So, it seems that Spark does some kind of "setup work" and then processes each mini-batch quite fast once it gets going.

Is this "setup work" going through the query planning through to the physical plan, for each mini-batch?

If so, does it make sense for Spark to do this each mini-batch?

Or is something else entirely going on? Am looking at Spark source code, but would appreciate feedback from someone that has gone through this exercise already.

Tx for any insights.

Comment: No issue, good question, that link from the Master I think states that it is no longer the case per microbatch. In an ideal world that may be the case though, on the fly. I will read today

Answer (score 2):

> Is this "setup work" going through the query planning through to the physical plan, for each mini-batch?

Partially yes for the execution-specific parts of a query plan of a streaming query to be filled out at runtime as follows (with links to respective code parts):

1. [Proper relations for data sources](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/MicroBatchExecution.scala#L65-L126) (e.g. [LocalRelation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/MicroBatchExecution.scala#L485) for no-data sources)
2. [Event-time watermark](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/MicroBatchExecution.scala#L364-L366)
3. [Current (micro-batch) time](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/MicroBatchExecution.scala#L364-L366)

> If so, does it make sense for Spark to do this each mini-batch?

Absolutely. There's no other way in Structured Streaming to short-circuit no-data sources, track the current time and watermark.

That's also the reason for an [extra no-data micro-batch for stateful operators](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/statefulOperators.scala#L139) when, say, watermark changes.

> Am looking at Spark source code, but would appreciate feedback from someone that has gone through this exercise already.

See [MicroBatchExecution](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/MicroBatchExecution.scala#L37) and [IncrementalExecution](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/IncrementalExecution.scala#L39).